# Mounting zfs network shares in Ubuntu LTS 20.04 using cifs- mount error(2): No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, mount, zfs, fstab, cifs

I have 3 Thecus NAS servers: a N5500 (Firmware: 5.03.02), a N5200XXX (Firmware: 5.03.02), and a N5550, (firmware 2.06.02.5.cdv) each configured as RAID 5. The N5500 and the N5200XXX are using zfs and the N5550 is using xfs. The share folders on each, configured as public, all work fine when connecting from the various Windows 10 machines I have laying about (a considerable number).

I am trying to mount these public shares in Ubuntu LTS 20.04. When I mount these using cifs (fstab prototype: //192.168.1.41/TV /media/Plex/TV cifs guest 0 0), the shares on the zfs boxes fail with mount error(2): No such file or directory, while those on the xfs box connect without a hitch. I've verified that I didn't fat-finger any of the mount points, and running smbclient -L  and hitting enter on the password request shows the folders I'm after on the two zfs machines, so I assume the Ubuntu server is reaching them.

Is it zfs that is causing my headache? Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: I've done some more testing. Both of the shares are huge so, thinking it might be a size thing, I created a share with one file on it on one of the NAS. No help. Still cannot connect via cifs. I discovered that I can connect with smbclient. Now I'm really befuddled!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here's what it was: the two NAS giving me trouble are old. To get them to mount, I had to add "vers=1.0" to the fstab line like so:

```
//192.168.1.41/TV /media/Plex/TV cifs guest,vers=1.0 0 0
```

Notably, most advice (and the man pages...) say that there should be a -o in front of the vers=1.0. Adding the -o was causing the mount parser to cough blood on that line. Also, not many sites talk about the dirty little secret of the "guest" user type (anonymous), and want to use credentials files, further confusing the issue for cifs noobs like myself.

So, once the -o and guest user syntax were resolved, it just became a matter of inserting descending version numbers in the line, saving, and invoking 'mount -a' until mount liked the results. I learned how to use several useful tools along the way, too!